# What determines the font size of a title bar in gnome

Tags: fonts, gnome, titlebar

Since owning a HiDPI notebook, this one irritates me: Nearly all my apps seem to ignore the title font setting:

```
% gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 
'Cantarell Bold 12'
```

Instead they display something in the order of 18pt or so. The interesting thing is that some apps behave correctly and the ones that do not behave consistently (they have all the same size). All are Gtk apps, including the shell itself.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

You see the shell has the same fontsize for its title bar (or whatever it is called) as my terminal (foreground window) and firefox (second). The third window is a gnome-settings dialog, which behaves as expected.

While firefox is a third party app and may make some things differently, it still uses Gtk, the shell might have an intentionally different appearance and only match the size by chance (although I doubt it). But why has the terminal window a dfferent title font size?

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following commands will reset the scaling factors to 1:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0`
- `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1`

With interfacse scaling factor 3:
[Scaling factor 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibt1S.png)

After setting to 1:
[Scaling factor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnHxx.png)